# Ошибка при отладке кода в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, отладка

При попытке запустить отладку всегда выдает одну и ту же ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.2\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 394, in _on_run
    r = r.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 1023: unexpected end of data
```

И так с абсолютно любым кодом. При поиске проблемы решением было оставить только символы 'ascii' в названии файла, но у меня такое не прошло
Использую Python 3.7
В других средах (проверял в VS Code) отладка работает

UPD: я не использовал метод decode в своем коде, ошибка возникает во внутренних файлах PyCharm

Comment: А что находится в `r`? Предположу, что содержание текстового файла. В таком случае нужно открыть файл, нажать `Файл->Сохранить как` и внизу, в списке кодировок, выбрать UTF-8.

Comment: В пути к файлу нет кириллицы?

Comment: Кодировка файла стоит UTF-8

Comment: В пути к файлу кириллица отсутствует

Comment: Файл сохраняется в UTF-8, никакой разницы нет.

Answer (score 0):

[Перевод](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004278/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xc3-in-position-34-unexpect)

Вы не можете произвольно разделить полученные байты и затем попросить UTF-8 декодировать их. UTF-8 представляет собой многобайтовую кодировку, что означает, что вы можете иметь от 1 до 6 байт для представления одного символа. Если вы разрежете его пополам и попросите Python декодировать, это приведет к неожиданному завершению ошибки данных.

Для более точного ответа и нахождения ошибки желательно показывать часть кода с ошибкой

Comment: Совершенно любой код, к примеру этот:

```python  
def quick_sort(arr: list):
    if len(arr) < 2:  
        return arr  
    pivot = arr[0]  
    left = [x for x in arr[1:] if x <= pivot]  
    right = [x for x in arr[1:] if x > pivot]  
  
    return [*quick_sort(left), pivot, *quick_sort(right)]  
  
  
print(quick_sort([5, 2, 9, 6, 1, 0, 5, 7, 6]))  
```